# What exactly is the operation scope in Property mediators in WSO2 esb?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

What exactly is the operation scope in Property mediators in WSO2 esb? 

Though I have read the standard documentation on this at https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Property+Mediator . But there is not much information on the operation scope. It just says

**Operation**: This scope is used to retrieve a property in the operation context level.


I am using this scope to access one property set inside an iterator mediator outside the iterator. It worked well. The code is

```
   <sequence key="Main">
        <iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="//source_record_details/source_record" sequential="true">
              <target sequence="Loop"></target>
           </iterate>
           <sequence key="OutsideLoop"></sequence>
</sequence>
```

In the sequence named Loop, I am setting property X with scope operation and I am able to access the value of X in the sequence OutsideLoop. But if I change the scope to default, I do not get the value of X.

Though this works for me, I am looking for some explanation on this. I hope that the operation scope is still local to the current execution of the proxy and is thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the WSO2 [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/XPath+Extension+Functions#XPathExtensionFunctions-operationscope),
You can retrieve a property in the operation context level from the operation scope.

The properties within iterated/cloned message with the operation scope are preserved in the in sequence even if you have configured your API resources to be sent through the fault sequence when faults exist.

A given property with the operation scope only exists in a single request and can be accessed by a single resource. The properties in this scope are passed to the error handler when the FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT property is set to true

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-SOAPfault also says When a SOAP error occurs in a response, the SOAPFault sent from the back end is received by the out sequence as a usual response by default. If this property is set to true, the SOAPFault is redirected to a fault sequence. Note that when this property is true, only properties in the 'operation' scope will be passed to the error handler, and other properties in the axis2 or default scopes will not be passed to the error handler.